# Riviera PRO and cocotb possible bug (libcocotbvhpi.dll' cannot be found)

Tags: python-3.7, msys2, cocotb

I am working with pyhton 3.7, Aldec Riviera Pro 2017, cocotb 1.3 and MSYS2.
When I run this test on jenkins and on remote PC I'm getting getting this issue. My log file looks like this:

```
VHPI: Loading library 'C:/JenkinsSlave/workspace/Diceros_-_Regression_Tests_CoCoTB_mao/Vivado/diceros/ip_repo/registers_1.0/sim/build/libs/x86_64/libcocotbvhpi.dll'
VHPI: Cannot load the "C:/JenkinsSlave/workspace/Diceros_-_Regression_Tests_CoCoTB_mao/Vivado/diceros/ip_repo/registers_1.0/sim/build/libs/x86_64/libcocotbvhpi.dll" library. The library does not exist or is corrupted.
```

Solution tried so far:

1. checked if the file is there and checked the dependencies of the dll file as well. (all good)
2. Discovered Riviera has its own gcc version which is different from MSYS2 (mingw64) --not sure if that is a problem ?
3. Played with environment variables (didn't work clearly)

Any suggestions will be helpful. I am really stuck at the moment. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer in https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/issues/1459, thanks!